# Error when using file_get_contents for class property

Tags: php, class

I get an error saying unexpected '(' when trying to do this in a class:

```
private $doglist = file_get_contents('dogdropdown.html');
```

Is that not allowed for some reason?
I also tried using a function like this:

```
public function getDogList(){
$list = file_get_contents('dogdropdown.html');
return $list;

}
```

which also didnt work. if I used include it does but doesnt inlcude it in the right place.

Comment: private $doglist; $doglist = file_get_contents('dogdropdown.html');, on constructor 4 exemple

Comment: You can't call a function when declaring a prop in the class body. You would have to put that code (`file_get_contents`) into `__construct()`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php: _“This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.”_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare a class property you can only assign basic scalar values or `null` for variables that should reference objects. If the property needs to hold the result of some operation you either make it static or assign the result either in the constructor or a method of the class.

In order to do what you are trying to do you need the following:

```
class MyClass {
    private $doglist;

    function __construct() {
        $this->doglist = file_get_contents('dogdropdown.html');
    }

}
```